# How can I plot a function defined as a derivative of another function?

Tags: plotting

How can I plot a function defined as a derivative of another function?

For example,

```
y[x_] := Sin[x]

y1[x_] := D[y[x], x] 

Plot[y1[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

doesn't work.  What is wrong with this? (y[x_] may of course be a much more complicated function!)

Comment: Like this: `Plot[y'[x], {x, 0, 2 π}]`.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 4):

You should pay attention to the differece of "=" and ":="

```
y[x_] := Sin[x] 
y1[x_] = D[y[x], x]
Plot[y1[m], {m, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

then you can get the result

[image]

If you write in the form of

```
 y1[x_] := D[y[x], x]
```

the mathematica will calculate y[x] firstly to get a number, then the derivative will make no sense.

Comment: Using `:=` one should evaluate the right-hand side `y1[x_] := Evaluate[D[y[x], x]]`.

Comment: Or just `Plot[y'[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also think about storing a pure function. Instead of:

```
y[x_] := Sin[x]/x
```

Define a function as:

```
z = Function[x, Sin[x]/x]
```

Then plot:

```
Plot[{z[x], z'[x]}, {x, 0, 6 Pi},
 PlotRange -> All]
```